# Do I need to install Yuri's Revenge and Red Alert 2 to use the Apocalypse mod?

Tags: mods, command-and-conquer-red-alert-2, command-and-conquer-yuris-revenge

I had played C&C:Red Alert 2 long time back. I want to play it again.

Is Yuri's Revenge an expansion pack to Red Alert 2 or is it completely different game?

Also, I want to use the Apocalypse mod. So which game do I need to install? Red Alert 2, Yuri's Revenge or both?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yuri's Revenge is the expansion for Red Alert 2. You need Red Alert 2 in order to install/play Yuri's Revenge.

The Apocalypse mod is for Yuri's Revenge, so you need both of the games installed in order to use it.

Comment: Author here. Yes, you need to install RA2 then YR and YR patch 1.001 (the patch is strongly recommended). Then you can use Apocalypse with full capabilities.